# How to setup transparent proxy for docker

Tags: docker

I have several external socks5 proxies, and I want to setup transparent proxy for different containers in docker. But I only found documents about setting HTTP(S) proxies for docker. What should I do if I want to forward *all* the traffic from docker through the external socks5 proxies?